# Using string as variable name

Tags: python

Is there any way for me to use a string to call a method of a class? Here's an example that will hopefully explain better (using the way I think it should be):

```
class helloworld():
    def world(self):
        print "Hello World!"

str = "world"
hello = helloworld()

hello.`str`()
```

Which would output `Hello World!`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Should the output be "hello world" or "Hello World!"?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use [`getattr`](http://docs.python.org/3.0/library/functions.html#getattr):

```
>>> class helloworld:
...     def world(self):
...         print("Hello World!")
... 
>>> m = "world"
>>> hello = helloworld()
>>> getattr(hello, m)()
Hello World!
```

- Note that the parens in `class helloworld()` as in your example are unnecessary, in this case.
- And, as [SilentGhost](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12855/silentghost) points out, [`str`](http://docs.python.org/3.0/library/functions.html#str) is an unfortunate name for a variable.

Comment: str is a bad choice for a variable name.

Answer (score 2):

*Warning: exec is a dangerous function to use, study it before using it*

You can also use the built-in function "exec":

```
>>> def foo(): print('foo was called');
...
>>> some_string = 'foo';
>>> exec(some_string + '()');
foo was called
>>>
```

Comment: The is really not a good idea. exec should be avoided when possible. getattr is made for this problem.

Comment: Don't confuse *how* to do something with whether it's *safe* or not. exec is indeed a dangerous function to use. However, there are ways to use it safely. In this case, you can pass the "globals" and "locals" context dictionaries in order to run exec in a "sandbox".

Comment: I've heard awful things about exec(), but this worked perfectly.

Comment: Keep in mind, Sliggy, that exec is indeed dangerous to use. Make sure you fully understand the weapon before handling it.

Answer (score -3):

one way is you can set variables to be equal to functions just like data

```
def thing1():
    print "stuff"

def thing2():
    print "other stuff"

avariable = thing1
avariable ()
avariable = thing2
avariable ()
```

And the output you'l get is

```
stuff
other stuff
```

Then you can get more complicated and have

```
somedictionary["world"] = world
somedictionary["anotherfunction"] = anotherfunction
```

and so on. If you want to automatically compile a modules methods into the dictionary use dir()

Comment: How can you get the output of thing1 by calling blah?

Answer (score -3):

What you're looking for is [exec](http://www.python.org/doc/2.5.2/ref/exec.html)

```
class helloworld():
    def world(self):
        print "Hello World!"

str = "world"
hello = helloworld()

completeString = "hello.%s()" % str

exec(completString)
```

Comment: I have never used "exec" before but I think I'll reconsider...  Up-modding.