# How to convert string to variable name?

Tags: python, string, variables, module, introspection

I would like to know how to convert a string input into a variable name to use into Python code. A concrete example:

```
def insrospect(foo, bar):
    requested_module = makestringvariable(foo)
    requested_object = makestringvariable(bar)
    import requested_module
    for item in inspect.getmemebers(requested_module.requested_object):
        member = makestringvariable(item[0])
        if callable(requested_object.member):
           print item

if __name__ == '__main__':
    introspect(somemodule, someobject)
```

So here above, because i do not know which module to introspect before launching, i need to convert the string to a usable module name and because `getmembers()` returns the members as strings, i also need them to be converted into usable variable names to check if they are callable.

Is there such a `makestringvariable()` function?

Comment: it's not very good idea to use "object" as a variable name, because it conflicts with Python2's "object" type or Python3's "object" class.

Comment: Please, please, please search: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+string+variable+name.  This question -- in this literal form -- has already been asked hundreds of times.

Comment: @S.Lott: i actually did look for these and looked into python doc since yesterday, but the questions ask here are to convert variable names into string and the one question regarding converting string to variable name is in fact about formating a string. Thanks for checking though, and if you can point to a questions the content of which answers my question i am ready to accept my mistake :)

Comment: @Benjamin: "but the questions ask [how] to convert variable names into string"  That's clearly false.  I guess you didn't really read them very carefully at all.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009831/using-string-as-variable-name, for example, is a duplicate.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

with the [__import__](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html?highlight=import#__import__) function and the [getattr](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#getattr) magic, you will be able to directly write this :

```
import importlib
def introspect(foo, bar):
    imported_module = importlib.import_module(foo)
    imported_object = getattr(imported_module, bar)
    for item in inspect.getmembers(imported_object):
        if callable(getattr(imported_object, item[0]):
           print item

if __name__ == '__main__':
    introspect(somemodule, someobject)
```

Comment: `__import__` won't return what you expect it to when the name contains dots, better to use `importlib.import_module`.

Comment: @Cat Plus Plus : great module, I used to split myself the parts of such import statements.
I've learned something great :) and edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks it's exactly what i needed, amazing :) So i could even add some member to a class this way like `getattr(self, string) = value`?

Comment: @Benjamin : use setattr(self, string, value) instead of getattr to set a value ;)

Comment: édric: even better! :) -- i loove Python :D

Answer (score 6):

You can't convert a string into a variable as such, because variables are part of your *code*, not of your *data*. Usually, if you have a need for "variable variables", as it were, you would use a dict:

```
data = {
    foo: foo_value,
    bar: bar_value
}
```

And then use `data[foo]` instead of trying to use `foo` as a variable. However, in this example you're actually asking about importing a module through a string, and about getting attributes using a string name, both of which are services Python provides: through the `__import__` and `getattr` functions.

Comment: After reading your comment on my answer I removed my comment and my -1. The current -1 is not mine.

Answer (score 3):

Members of a module are just attributes on that module, so you can use `getattr` on the module object to retrieve them.

The module objects themselves are stored in the `sys.modules` dictionary:

```
module = sys.modules[modulename]
member = getattr(module, membername)
```

Comment: If the module isn't imported yet, though, it won't exist in `sys.modules` either. You would need `__import__` for that.

Comment: True enough, but I was assuming it's been imported already. :-)